# How to ensure true one-to-many relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have one-to-many relationship between entities - RentalUnit and Review . All tests run fine, except when i am adding the same review to different RentalUnit instances as following:

```
def review3 = Review.build().save(flush: true)
def rentalUnit2 = RentalUnit.build().
    addToReviews(review2).addToReviews(review3).save(flush: true)
assert rentalUnit.reviews.contains(review2)
```

It seems that GORM and the `addTo*` method doesn't seem to care if i am adding the same Review instance, so i am guessing there is something missing in my domain classes. What would that be?

Thank you for helping

p.s.

```
class Review {
    String submittedBy
    String content
    String dateReceived
    boolean isApproved

    static belongsTo = RentalUnit

    static mapping = {
        content type: 'text'
    }

    static constraints = {
        submittedBy blank: false, size: 3..50
        content blank: false, size: 5..2500

    }
}

class RentalUnit {
    String name
    String nickname
    Address address
    static hasMany = [reviews:Review]

    static mapping = {
        reviews cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
    }

    static constraints = {
        name blank: false, unique: true, size: 4..10
        nickname blank: false, size: 5..60
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it doesn't care - it doesn't change any other objects' properties. Even about the other end of relationship - `review2.rentalUnit` (if such field existed) will be null here.

The Review will disappear from `rentalUnit.reviews` (or `review2.rentalUnit` would be assigned) the next time the object is loaded from database.

You can assign `review2.rentalUnit` by hand and validate if it's been added to another `RentalUnit`, though - the assignment will do no harm.

**edit**: let's go through the code step-by-step.

```
rentalUnit1.addToReviews(review2)
```

Here `review2` is added to `rentalUnit1.reviews`. `review2.rentalUnit` is NOT assigned, but after save in the database it would point to `rentalUnit1`. The only persistent representation of `RentalUnit.reviews` field is a child-to-parent reference field, `Review.rentalUnit`.

```
def rentalUnit2 = ...
rentalUnit2.addToReviews(review2).addToReviews(review3).save(flush: true)
```

Here `review2` is added to `rentalUnit2.reviews`. `review2.rentalUnit` is NOT assigned again. `review2` is NOT removed from `rentalUnit1.reviews` BUT, after save, in the database, it will point to `rentalUnit2`.

```
assert rentalUnit1.reviews.contains(review2)
```

`review2` was NOT removed from `rentalUnit1.reviews`, so the assertion will pass. BUT in the next session `rentalUnit1` and `rentalUnit2` will have the correct sets of `review`s - only `rentalUnit2` will have `review2`.

Now, if you want to always maintain Java representation consistent, implment a method like this:

```
class RentalUnit {
    RentalUnit addToReviewsAndCheck(Review r) {
         if (r.rentalUnit == this) return;
         if (r.rentalUnit != null) {
             r.rentalUnit.removeFromReviews(r)
         }
         r.rentalUnit = this
         addToReviews(r)
    }
}
```

but it's an overkill, as for me.

Comment: Thank You Victor. Please correct me, but that means it is physically not true one-to-many relationship because the same review is physically referencing two different RentalUnits (if the shared review is updated, it updates the two different RentalUnits review's collections). So, to implement true one-to-many relationship, we have to check if the review about to add for particular RentalUnit is not referenced in another Rental Unit....for that is there any built in mechanism (i.e. constraints,etc) or we manually travel through each RentalUnit.reviews collection which can be very expensive...

Comment: Physically, there is only one reference to `RentalUnit` in `Review`. `belingsTo` creates an implicit field, `Review.rentalUnit`, which you can check (http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html). Hope I got your question right.

Comment: Thank You Victor. I appreciate. English is not my first language, so i apologize not able express clearly myself. The relationship One-to-Many from RentalUnit to Review == Many-to-One from Review to RentalUnit, correct? However the particular shared Review is pointing more then one RentalUnit, unless we manually enforce otherwise at the time adding Review to RentalUnit. Is this make sense? Is there error in my rational?...thnks

Comment: It's fine, I believe I got you correct, the way you described it. I don't see any physical possibility for a `Review` to point to several  `RentalUnit`, `belongsTo` creates only a single field. So the problem you're looking for must be the one that it's added to two `RentalUnit`'s `reviews` collection, correct? Then all the answer remains the same - it's OK and the status quo will be restored in the next session.

Comment: Yes, Victor. The same review is added to two different RentalUnits. This shared review if updated reflects the change on both RentalUnits.reviews collections...so, even thou there is no reference the shared review to any of the two rental units, it is tied to both rental units...

Comment: We're going in circles. I added a more detailed description of what is hhappening in your code, hope it should make it clear.

Comment: Thank You Victor a lot. I think i finally got it. I summarized it in my blog section - 'java.util.NoSuchElementException - Challenging One-To-Many' (http://margotskapacs.com/2012/11/domain-object-one-to-many-relationship-in-grails-gorm-and-sql-relational-db/)